# Spark S3A write omits upload part without failure

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I'm using Spark 2.4.0 with Hadoop 2.7, hadoop-aws 2.7.5 to write Datasets to parquet files on S3A. Occasionally a file part will be missing; i.e. part `00003` here:

```
> aws s3 ls my-bucket/folder/
2019-02-28 13:07:21          0 _SUCCESS
2019-02-28 13:06:58   79428651 part-00000-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-02-28 13:06:59   79586172 part-00001-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-02-28 13:07:00   79561910 part-00002-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-02-28 13:07:01   79192617 part-00004-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-02-28 13:07:07   79364413 part-00005-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-02-28 13:07:08   79623254 part-00006-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-02-28 13:07:10   79445030 part-00007-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-02-28 13:07:10   79474923 part-00008-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-02-28 13:07:11   79477310 part-00009-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-02-28 13:07:12   79331453 part-00010-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-02-28 13:07:13   79567600 part-00011-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-02-28 13:07:13   79388012 part-00012-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-02-28 13:07:14   79308387 part-00013-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-02-28 13:07:15   79455483 part-00014-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-02-28 13:07:17   79512342 part-00015-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-02-28 13:07:18   79403307 part-00016-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-02-28 13:07:18   79617769 part-00017-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-02-28 13:07:19   79333534 part-00018-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-02-28 13:07:20   79543324 part-00019-5789ebf5-b55d-4715-8bb5-dfc5c4e4b999-c000.snappy.parquet
```

What concerns me the most is that the Spark application **SUCCEEDS**.

- stderr looks perfectly normal for both the driver and executor
- stdout looks perfectly normal for the driver
- only stdout for the executor gives any indication something went wrong:

```
2019-02-28 21:05:39 INFO  AmazonHttpClient:448 - Unable to execute HTTP request: Read timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:161)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:278)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:286)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:257)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:207)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:684)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:384)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3480)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:960)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.deleteUnnecessaryFakeDirectories(S3AFileSystem.java:1144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.finishedWrite(S3AFileSystem.java:1133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AOutputStream.close(S3AOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopPositionOutputStream.close(HadoopPositionOutputStream.java:64)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.end(ParquetFileWriter.java:685)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.close(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:122)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.close(ParquetRecordWriter.java:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.close(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.releaseResources(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1394)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:168)
...
```

(this stack trace repeated 6 times)

I am tweaking the Hadoop S3A configurations to see if this can happen less frequently, but what I really want is for the application to **FAIL** if this happens. As it is, downstream applications start, expecting data to be present, and produce incorrect results due to the missing data.

How can I change Spark/Hadoop's behavior in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be impossible to get around this issue (at least in Hadoop 2.7), so for now I've added an assertion after each Spark S3 write ensuring that the number of file parts matches the number of partitions in the Dataset's RDD:

```
  def overwriteParquetS3(
    ds: Dataset[_],
    bucket: String,
    folder: String
  ): Unit = {
    val numPartitions = ds.rdd.getNumPartitions
    val destination = GeneralUtils.joinPaths("s3a://", bucket, folder)

    ds
        .write
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .parquet(destination)

    val fs = FileSystem.get(
      URI.create(s"s3a://$bucket/"),
      ds.sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
    )
    val writtenFiles = fs.listFiles(new Path(destination), false)
    val parts = new ArrayBuffer[LocatedFileStatus]()
    while (writtenFiles.hasNext) {
      val next = writtenFiles.next()
      val name = next.getPath.getName
      if (name.startsWith("part-") && name.endsWith(".parquet")) {
        parts += next
      }
    }

    val filePartStr = parts
        .sortBy(_.getPath.getName)
        .map((fileStatus) => s"${fileStatus.getModificationTime} ${fileStatus.getBlockSize} ${fileStatus.getPath.getName}")
        .mkString("\n\t")
    assert(
      parts.length == numPartitions,
      s"Expected to write dataframe with $numPartitions partitions in $destination but instead " +
          s"found ${parts.length} written parts!\n\t$filePartStr"
    )

    println(s"Confirmed that there numPartitions $numPartitions = ${parts.length} written parts")
  }
```

This seems to be catching all the cases where the write should error but doesn't.

Comment: something is still going wrong with the FS bonding here, though it's not a simple AWS S3 consistency. I'd consider actually filing a bug with spark JIRA (point to it here) & We can look at it. FWIW, Cloudera did qualify the Hadoop 3.0 release of the connector with Ceph, I don't recall any specific bugs being filed related to that qualification (and I would have heard).

Comment: Thans for advice, crated JIRA here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27098

Comment: @SteveLoughran mirroring my comment in the JIRA, what do you make of it that there are no DEBUG logs at all about the missing part, rename or otherwise? Seems like Spark is just forgetting about that partition?

Comment: try and see if you can replicate the problem with a different FS, or switching between the hadoop v1 and v2 commit algorithms. the spark driver will tell a task to commit when it reports in; if it doesnt succeed spark will try with a new task. Job commit (v1) promotes all committed task output to the dest dir. V2: just creates the _SUCCESS file, as the task commits straight to the dest dir. Both use rename, and rely on consistent listings

Comment: +paper on the commit protocols. https://github.com/steveloughran/zero-rename-committer/releases  That it works at all is wondrous

Comment: I now found `19/03/28 16:07:24 INFO SparkHadoopMapRedUtil: No need to commit output of task because needsTaskCommit=false: attempt_20190328160411_0004_m_000113_343` in the executor logs, which applies only to the attempts for missing file parts. The `needsTaskCommit` comes from ParquetOutputCommitter. However, I don't see how to change committer without rebuilding with Hadoop 3 - the configuration doesn't seem to be in Spark 2.4.0 or Hadoop 2.7 docs or code?

Answer (score 0):

that's called "side effects of an inconsistent filesystem with a job committer which depends on consistent directory listings to rename work into place"

Fixes

- Use a consistency layer; for S3A that's S3Guard
- Use an alternate committer: For ASF Spark and Hadoop 3.1, that's the "zero rename committer"
- Radical but best in long term: Use a different layout for data, with Apache Iceberg being the one I have in mind

Update: This is not true in this specific instance, as Ceph is the FS and it is consistent.

Comment: Those look like useful tools, but

* The first two are not available in Hadoop 2.7.
* I'm not actually using AWS, and will not begin to.

Hadoop is clearly aware of the failure in this case. The eventual consistency of S3-compliant data lakes is not at fault. With that in mind, how can I get this to throw the error?

Comment: you said you "parquet files on S3A", so either you are using AWS S3 or a third party one  If you are using a third party S3 store then it should be consistent, but you are sadly on your own. It'll be configuration problem, such as some process still trying to to AWS us-east for S3 access.

Comment: BTW, regarding that stack trace: That's just a timeout during some cleanup, something which is caught and ignored in recent hadoop releases. Unlikely to be the root cause

Comment: No, I am neither using AWS nor a third party. This is Ceph instance on my own hardware. Definitely not a configuration issue, but you might be right about the stack trace having nothing to do with the write failure.